# Shrink into one page with ClosedXML

Tags: excel, closedxml, shrink

I create an Excel sheet with ClosedXML, everything looks good now but sometimes the content goes overflow a little bit. To ensure that won't happen, I want to shrink the content into one page no matter what.

So question is: How do I shrink everything into one page with ClosedXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPages(1, 1);